# Use specific jvm installation when call java application from php code

Tags: java, php, linux, ubuntu, path

I have two installations of JDK on my account and I do not have root access to change the default one which is "usr/bin/java" to  specific one /home/username/jdk/bin/java"

I tried to do the following in my php code:

```
 $JAVA_HOME = "/home/username/jdk";
 $PATH = "$JAVA_HOME/bin:".getenv('PATH');
 putenv("JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME");
```

But when I execute the following just below above mentioned lines:

```
which java
```

I got `/usr/bin/java`

Any idea please how to make it works? The java application I want to run from php code does not work on the default one.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `JAVA_HOME` as temporary parameter for the context of your application, i.e. right before the command (see the second command, the others just show that the variable is only set for that one command):

```
> java -version
java version "1.8.0"

> JAVA_HOME=~/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/ java -version
java version "1.7.0_51"

> java -version
java version "1.8.0"
```

In PHP:

```
exec("JAVA_HOME=~/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/ java yourapplication");
```

Source: [Bash Reference Manual – Environment](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Environment)

> The environment for any simple command or function may be augmented temporarily by prefixing it with parameter assignments, as described in Shell Parameters. These assignment statements affect only the environment seen by that command.

To see the differences in a browser I tested with this ugly PHP snippet:

```
<?php
echo "<pre>" . shell_exec('java -version 2>&1') . "</pre>";
echo "<pre>" . shell_exec('JAVA_HOME=~/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk java -version 2>&1') . "</pre>";
echo "<pre>" . shell_exec('~/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/bin/java -version 2>&1') . "</pre>";
?>
```

You may also use a specific version of the `java` executable by explicitly using it to run your app:

```
shell_exec("~/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/bin/java -version");
```

Comment: This is what I tried:
`$cmd = "JAVA_HOME=/home/username/jdk1.7.0_51/ java -version 2>&1";
$output=passthru($cmd,$status);`
output:
`java version "1.6.0_33" OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.5) (6b33-1.13.5-1ubuntu0.12.04) OpenJDK Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)`

So it did not work this way.

Comment: I just put this line into a php file: `passthru("JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home java -version");`. It shows `java version "1.7.0_51"` when run from the command line. Are you executing the PHP file through a webserver?

Comment: Yes I am executing it through a webserver and I changed jdk folder ownership to www-data.

Comment: Works for me as well. Try qualifying `java` executable with the complete path: `/home/username/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/java`.

Comment: When I executed:
 `echo "<pre>" . shell_exec('/home/username/jdk1.7.0_51
  6 /bin/java -version 2>&1') . "</pre>";`
I got:
`sh: 2: /bin/java: not found`

Even it worked form the command line and the folder is owned by www-data group.

Comment: You got a space (and a 6) in the path to `java`. Try `shell_exec('/home/username/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/java -version 2>&1')`.

Comment: Sorry this is mistake why copying to here, but it is correct I just copied the path into command line from php code and it worked.  I copied the path from  error message:
`sh: 1: /home/username/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/java: not found`
Into command line and it worked.

Comment: Ok, can't help you at this point, this seems to be depending on your system or setup.

Comment: Thanks alot you did the best :)

Answer (score 0):

If feasible, qualify the `java` command, e.g. `/home/username/jdk/bin/java`, when running your Java program.

This way you can even use multiple different JVM's in different places of your PHP code.

**Note:** I know that using qualified access like this works on Windows, even if JAVA_HOME points to a different installation. I'm assuming the same is true for Linux.

Comment: It did not work on linux, it gives me: 
sh: 1: /home/username/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/java: not found
The same command from command line works well.